# How to efficiently generate this matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have already had a row vector a of dimension d which only contains elements 0 or 1.

I want generate a r by d matrix A, where A satisfies

```
for column j = 1,2 .... d
if a[j] = 1, then A[:,j] = 1. That's, the corresponding column will be all 1's 
if a[j] = 0, then A[:,j] = 0. ....
```

I think it looks quite straightforward. But I don't know how to generate it efficiently in python ( or in other languages).

Note that r = 1,000 and d = 100,000

(The reason why I want to generate this matrix A is that given another d by n matrix B, C = A*B will be r by n which the rows of C correspond to the non-zero elements in vector a.)

Comment: You want [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> r, d = 1000, 100000
>>> a = np.random.rand(d).round()
>>> A = a * np.ones((r, 1))
>>> A.shape
(1000, 100000)
>>> a
array([ 1.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.])
>>> A
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be doing matrix multiplication or math in general in Python, use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org).

The rows of `A` all have the same value, so the *efficient* way to calculate it is to build only one row. You already have that row, `a`.

NumPy can also broadcast the values of an array, making a 1-dimensional vector act like a 2-dimensional array with repeated values. This is memory-efficient since you do not need to actually allocate space for the repeated values.

So, in NumPy you might perform the calculation like this:

```
import numpy as np

r, d, n = 1000, 100000, 1000
a = np.random.randint(2, size=d)
A = a
print(A.shape)
# (100000,)

B = np.random.random((d, n))
print(B.shape)
# (100000, 1000)

C = A.dot(B)
print(C.shape)
# (1000,)
```

The result, `C` is "`of shape (n,)`" -- which is NumPy-talk for a 1D vector of `n` elements -- rather than an array of shape `(r,n)` since, just like `A`, all the rows have the same value. There is no need to repeat them.

Comment: Isn't `C` simply `A.dot(B)`?